# Present perfect and reported speech

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses

I would like to understand the following (because Google returns suspiciously low number of records for this form):

> > A: *I saw him there*.
> >     B (joins the conversation): *Hey, have you seen John lately*?
> >      C: *He has just said he had seen him there*.

Is it OK to use present perfect and then reported speech shifted back (from past simple to past perfect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present Perfect is OK with *just* (it points at the latest moment), but then you don't need Past Perfect: **Past Simple** is enough  here to put the reported event *before* the event 'he *has* (said)'.